# xsl:variable select with concat

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to build an XSLT to convert an XML-format Excel spreadsheet to another XML format.

Part of my code is:

```
            <!-- SPREADSHEET VALUES -->
        <xsl:variable name="cluster" select="./ss:Cell[1]/ss:Data"/>
        <xsl:variable name="server" select="./ss:Cell[2]/ss:Data"/>
        <xsl:variable name="database" select="./ss:Cell[3]/ss:Data"/>
        <xsl:variable name="instance" select="./ss:Cell[4]/ss:Data"/>
        <xsl:variable name="scheme" select="./ss:Cell[5]/ss:Data"/>
        <xsl:variable name="dblocation" select="./ss:Cell[6]/ss:Data"/>
        <xsl:variable name="dbdescription" select="./ss:Cell[7]/ss:Data"/>
        <xsl:variable name="dbstatus" select="./ss:Cell[8]/ss:Data"/>
        <xsl:variable name="infraservicesla" select="./ss:Cell[9]/ss:Data"/>
        <xsl:variable name="dbms" select="./ss:Cell[10]/ss:Data"/>
        <xsl:variable name="edition" select="./ss:Cell[11]/ss:Data"/>
        <xsl:variable name="version" select="./ss:Cell[12]/ss:Data"/>
        <xsl:variable name="clustertype" select="./ss:Cell[13]/ss:Data"/>

        <!-- GENERATED VALUES -->
        <xsl:variable name="artifactname" select="{concat('[',$dblocation,'-',$database,'] ',$dbdescription,' (Artifact)')}"/>
```

UPDATE: the last line actually did not fail as I said when I entered the question, as one tool reported, it failed somewhere else.

ANSWER: I know now that I do *not* need curly braces here:

```
<xsl:variable name="infraservicename" select="concat('[', $server, '-', $instance, '-', $scheme, '] ', $dbdescription, ' (Infrastructure Service)')"/>
<xsl:variable name="infraservicexmiid" select="concat('[', $server, '-', $instance, '-', $scheme, '] DBINSTANCE (Infrastructure Service)')"/>
```

But I need them here:

```
<InfrastructureService name="{$infraservicename}" xmi.id="{$infraservicexmiid}" xmi.type='InfrastructureService' />
```

I haven't found good documentation yet. I normally go to w3schools for this, but I haven't seen this explained there (no mention of curly braces). Any tips for good documentation to learn the syntax well? And thanks all who replied.

Comment: The second approach looks better. Have you checked if the other variables have contents and are therefore correct?

Comment: Please show a minimal, reproducible example of your problem instead of snippets that we cannot run. Help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: In what way does `<xsl:variable name="artifactname" select="concat('[',$dblocation,'-',$database,'] ',$dbdescription,' (Artifact)')"/>` fail, which error do you get? `<xsl:variable name="artifactname" select="{concat('[',$dblocation,'-',$database,'] ',$dbdescription,' (Artifact)')}"/>` should of course give a syntax error for the `select` expression.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach is obviously wrong because of the curly braces.

The second approach looks OK. But if it "fails", why don't you tell us how it fails? That's where all problem investigation starts - with the symptoms of the failure.

Comment: I agree. There is one of my problems. This XSLT (and the input XML) is read by some modelling tool which does not display decent parse error messages. So it is trial and error for me. I tried some XSLT checkers on the net, but they only gave errors like "15 errors" (on the entire script) without saying what or where.

Comment: OK, so your primary problems are (a) that you haven't found any decent documentation, and (b) that you are using the wrong tools. On (a) there are a number of good books on XSLT to suit different tastes; in my personal experience almost any book does a better job of explaining the concepts than your average online site. On (b) it is well worth investing in a decent IDE such as oXygen or Stylus Studio.